# Gatsby With Contentful Rich Text Images Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, contentful

I'm trying to build a details page of an article, I'm using the Contentful CMS to display content. I've got it to display text but cannot get it to display images.

Details.js page

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from '../../components/layout'
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from '@contentful/rich-text-types';

export default function ProjectDetails({ data, location }) {

    const { title, subtitle, details } = data.allContentfulProject.nodes[0]

    const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>;

    const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>;

    const options = {
        renderMark: {
            [MARKS.BOLD]: (text) => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
        },
        renderNode: {
            [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
            [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
                return (
                    <>
                        <h2>Embedded Asset</h2>
                        <pre>
                            <code>{JSON.stringify(node, null, 2)}</code>
                        </pre>
                    </>
                )
            },
        },
    };

    return (

        <Layout>
            <div>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <h2>{subtitle}</h2>
                <p>{renderRichText(details, options)}</p>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export const query = graphql`
query getThisProjectBySlug($slug: String) {
    allContentfulProject(filter: {slug: {eq: $slug}}) {
      nodes {
        slug
        id
        subtitle
        title
        details {
          raw
          references {
            file {
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  `
```

Contentful Rich Text JSON, as you can see it detects that there are two images but it cannot see the file sources; the "content" array under "nodeType":"embedded-asset-block" is blank.

```
{
   "nodeType":"document",
   "data":{
      
   },
   "content":[
      {
         "nodeType":"paragraph",
         "content":[
            {
               "nodeType":"text",
               "value":"this is a test project :) ",
               "marks":[
                  
               ],
               "data":{
                  
               }
            }
         ],
         "data":{
            
         }
      },
      {
         "nodeType":"embedded-asset-block",
         "content":[
            
         ],
         "data":{
            "target":{
               "sys":{
                  "id":"rqEe5eH8P201VsVhqDAHc",
                  "type":"Link",
                  "linkType":"Asset"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "nodeType":"paragraph",
         "content":[
            {
               "nodeType":"text",
               "value":"hello more text",
               "marks":[
                  
               ],
               "data":{
                  
               }
            }
         ],
         "data":{
            
         }
      },
      {
         "nodeType":"embedded-asset-block",
         "content":[
            
         ],
         "data":{
            "target":{
               "sys":{
                  "id":"1WoarVHbjoQeTLawvMBMaj",
                  "type":"Link",
                  "linkType":"Asset"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "nodeType":"paragraph",
         "content":[
            {
               "nodeType":"text",
               "value":"",
               "marks":[
                  
               ],
               "data":{
                  
               }
            }
         ],
         "data":{
            
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Have you removed your cache by `gatsby clean`?

Comment: I've tried that just now, nothing has changed. No idea what I'm doing wrong and the information on the internet is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from '../../components/layout'
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from '@contentful/rich-text-types';

export default function ProjectDetails({ data, location }) {

    const { title, subtitle, details } = data.allContentfulProject.nodes[0]

    const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>;

    const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>;

    const options = {
        renderMark: {
            [MARKS.BOLD]: (text) => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
        },
        renderNode: {
            "embedded-asset-block": node => {
              const { gatsbyImageData } = node.data.target
              if (!gatsbyImageData) {
                // asset is not an image
                return null
              }
              return <GatsbyImage image={image} />
            },
            [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
            [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
                return (
                    <>
                        <h2>Embedded Asset</h2>
                        <pre>
                            <code>{JSON.stringify(node, null, 2)}</code>
                        </pre>
                    </>
                )
            },
        },
    };

    return (

        <Layout>
            <div>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <h2>{subtitle}</h2>
                <p>{renderRichText(details, options)}</p>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export const query = graphql`
query getThisProjectBySlug($slug: String) {
    allContentfulProject(filter: {slug: {eq: $slug}}) {
      nodes {
        slug
        id
        subtitle
        title
        details {
          raw
          references {
            file {
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  `
```

*Modified from: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#embedding-an-image-in-a-rich-text-field*

The key for the rendering node (`renderNode`) needs to display a `GatsbyImage` component.

Just in case, check the `node` to see the internal structure before destructuring as:

```
const { gatsbyImageData } = node.data.target
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, still doesn't appear to work: 26:23  error  'GatsbyImage' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
  26:42  error  'image' is not defined        no-undef

Comment: I think the problem is that the actual content is blank in the raw JSON data this is being returned for some reason: "nodeType":"embedded-asset-block",
         "content":[
            
         ],    

it recognises that there is content there, but it doesn't seem to see what's actually inside them. Maybe something wrong with the way I've placed the images in Contentful perhaps?

Comment: Well of course you need to import `GatsbyImage`, as any other React component (`import { GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"`). Try adding a `console.log` above the `return`, inside `embedded-asset-block`. If it's printed, the block is detected, otherwise the issue can be in the way you upload the image but is odd.